# What exactly is "Landau level mixing" and how does it change the Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-hall-effect

I've read of Landau level mixing ("LL-mixing") in several papers, e.g. [this one](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-017-00824-w) which in its supplementary information accounts for LL-mixing through the random-phase approximation, but I've yet to find a resource that gives a clear definition of what LL-mixing is in general.

What are papers like this referring to by Landau level mixing? What does it physically represent, and how is it written in terms of operators?